# What do these lines in `dna2protein.pl` do?

Tags: perl

I'm a newbie to perl and I found a script to [convert a DNA sequence to protein sequence using Perl](http://www.techcuriosity.com/resources/bioinformatics/dna2protein.php). I don't understand what some lines in that script do, specially the following:

```
my(%g)=('TCA'=>'S','TCC'=>'S','TCG'=>'S','TCT'=>'S','TTC'=>'F','TTT'=>'F','TTA'=>'L','TTG'=>'L','TAC'=>'Y','TAT'=>'Y','TAA'=>'_','TAG'=>'_','TGC'=>'C','TGT'=>'C','TGA'=>'_','TGG'=>'W','CTA'=>'L','CTC'=>'L','CTG'=>'L','CTT'=>'L','CCA'=>'P','CCC'=>'P','CCG'=>'P','CCT'=>'P','CAC'=>'H','CAT'=>'H','CAA'=>'Q','CAG'=>'Q','CGA'=>'R','CGC'=>'R','CGG'=>'R','CGT'=>'R','ATA'=>'I','ATC'=>'I','ATT'=>'I','ATG'=>'M','ACA'=>'T','ACC'=>'T','ACG'=>'T','ACT'=>'T','AAC'=>'N','AAT'=>'N','AAA'=>'K','AAG'=>'K','AGC'=>'S','AGT'=>'S','AGA'=>'R','AGG'=>'R','GTA'=>'V','GTC'=>'V','GTG'=>'V','GTT'=>'V','GCA'=>'A','GCC'=>'A','GCG'=>'A','GCT'=>'A','GAC'=>'D','GAT'=>'D','GAA'=>'E','GAG'=>'E','GGA'=>'G','GGC'=>'G','GGG'=>'G','GGT'=>'G');
if(exists $g{$codon})
{
return $g{$codon};
}
else
{
print STDERR "Bad codon \"$codon\"!!\n";
exit;
}
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Which lines don't you understand in there?

Comment: `print STDERR` aka `warn`. `print STDERR ...; exit` aka `die`. `die "Bad codon: '$codon'" unless exists $g{$codon}; return $g{$codon};`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My perl is rusty but anyway.

The first line creates a hash (which is perls version of a hash table). The variable is called `g` (a bad name BTW). The `%` sigil before `g` is used to indicate that it is a hash. Perl uses sigils to denote types. The hash is initialises using the double barrelled arrow syntax. `'TTT'=>'F'` creates an entry `TTT` in the hash table with value `F`. The `my` is used to give the variable a local scope.

The next few lines are fairly self explanatory. It will check whether the hash contains an entry with key `$codon`. The `$` sigil is used to indicate that it's a *scalar* value. If if `exists`, you get the value. Otherwise, it prints the message specified to the standard error.

Comment: Good explanation. A Perl hash (%g here) could be called an *unordered associative array*. The code snippet here is a part of a function (`return` only makes sens inside a function). The difficult part for Perl beginners is the changing sigils: `%g` is the hash, and `$g{TT}` is a value in the hash. It means `$g{...}` always refer ta a hash, while `$g[...]` would refer to an array, and `$g` to a plain scalar.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're new to Perl, you should read a little about Perl itself before you try to decrypt it's syntax on your own. (Perl values a good Huffman encoding, and is also somewhat encrypted. ;-)Start with the 'perldoc perlintro' command, and go from there. If you're using Ubunutu, for instance, this documentation can be installed via

```
 $ sudo apt-get install perl-doc
```

but it is also available in this file: [Perl Reference documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.tar.gz)

In addition to perlintro, some other suggested reading is perlsyn (syntax description), perldata (data structures), perlop (operators, including quotes), perlreftut (intro to references), and perlvar (predefined variables and their meanings), in roughly that order.

I learnt perl from these, and I still refer to them often.

Also, if your DNA script has POD documentation, then you can view that neatly by typing

```
$ perldoc <script-filename>
```

(of course, POD documentation is listed in the source, in a rougher form; read perlpod for more details on documentation fromat)

Comment: Yes I guess you are right, I should dig in to the language... Thanks for your response ...

Comment: Perl is very eccentric, but there's a logic to its madness.

Answer (score 3):

If you are new to Perl with an interest to understand more quickly, you might begin with this web collection [learn.perl](http://learn.perl.org/).  A nice supplement is the online Perl documentation of [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/).  Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links... They will be really helpful... :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case it looks like the %g hash serves as both a way to identify whether a codon is within the set of valid condons (hash keys) and for some mapping to what type of codon it is (hash value).

Hashes serve as a way to link unique keys with a value, but they also serve as unique lists of keys.  In some cases you may see keys added to a hash and set to undef.  This is a good sign that the hash is being used to track unique values of some type.

Answer (score 1):

The codon is being passed in to the function, upper cased and then a hash of codons is checked to see if there is codon of that value registered. If the codon exists the registered value for that codon is returned, otherwise an error is outputed and the program ends.

the `my (%g)` is creating a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which is a structure that allows you to quickly look up a value by giving a key for that value. So for instance 'TCA'=>'S' maps the value 'S' to 'TCA'. If you ask the g hash for the value held for 'TCA' you will get 'S' (`$g{'TCA'} //will equal 'S'` )